# jquery draggable() in FF and Opera not working properly

Tags: jquery-ui, iframe, draggable

I have in iframe table trs which  draggable and droppable(jquery). Its work in chrome and ie normally, but when I want to drag and drop in FF, i must do 2 clicks to change trs.

```
    $(this).draggable({ helper: 'clone', iframeFix: true, cursor: "move", cursorAt: { top: 600, left: 155 } });

                  $(childrensDraggableZone).droppable({
                      accept: '.dragdrop',
                      activeClass: "ui-state-hover",
                      hoverClass: "ui-state-active",
                      drop: function(event, ui) {

                          var draggable = ui.draggable, droppable = $(this),
                              dragPos = draggable.position(), dropPos = droppable.position();
                          draggable.css({
                                  left: dropPos.left + 'px',
                                  top: dropPos.top + 'px'
                              });

                          droppable.css({
                                  left: dragPos.left + 'px',
                                  top: dragPos.top + 'px'
                              });
                          draggable.swap(droppable);
                      }
                  });
```